# Класс для обработки HTTP-запросов?

Tags: xcode, objective-c, ios, iphone

Как правильно организовать работу с http-запросами?
У меня сейчас 3 вьюшки и все запросы обрабатываю в каждом из них.

Как сделать один класс для запросов, который бы возвращал полученные данные в нужную мне вьюшку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй библиотеку [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать применить библиотеку [AFNetworking](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/index.html) и паттерн Model View Controller Store описано  в книге Хиллегасс, Конвэй: [Программирование под iOS. Для профессионалов](http://www.labirint.ru/books/370625/)